# Extending relay-compiler to emit TypeScript definitions

Tags: typescript, relay, relaymodern

I understand there are extensibility points for modifying the `relay-compiler` output (https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/relay-compiler.html#advanced-usage). I'd like to explore creating TypeScript definitions instead of Flow type, but I'm having a hard time finding good (any) resources on how to get started. The link references [RelayCompilerPublic.js](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/packages/relay-compiler/RelayCompilerPublic.js), but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

EDIT: I just realized this question is probably too broad for SO. Effectively moving this to the [relay repo](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1997) until I have time to rephrase the question above.